# Trouble Installing Ubuntu from USB

Tags: installation, live-usb

I have a PC with Windows 7 on one disk.

First, I use WUBI to install Ubuntu, but I can not see the ubuntu logo.
Then, I try to install 11.10 on the disk, but I get the same result.
And then I try to install 12.04 with USB, but I get the same result again.

When I restart the computer and choose to boot from USB, I can see a screen with a gray menu containing some options such as *run Ubuntu on the USB*, *install Ubuntu on disk*, and others.

When I choose "*install Ubuntu on disk*", the computer outputs some lines of text, and the screen becomes a mess. After a little while, the screen's power light goes dark.

**UPDATES:**

**Machine Information:**

- CPU: AMD Athlon II*3 440
- Motherboard: GA-MA77OT-UD3P
- VideoCard: ATI Radeon HD 5600/5700

Comment: So you're not even able to boot from the LiveCD/USB... Mind posting your computer specifications? It *might* be a graphics-related or power-related issue. The output of text lines during the boot is normal: can you read any of the last lines? maybe they contain useful information...

Comment: My computer infomation is :
CPU:AMD Athlon II*3 440
Motherboard:GA-MA77OT-UD3P
VideoCard:ATI Radeon HD 5600/5700.

I can not see the last line,it disappear very quickly...

Comment: I download the desktop-i386.iso.
Is this wrong?I don't if I should download the amd64.iso.

Comment: Yes, the lines may disappear very quickly indeed. Now since it seems to be a graphics-related issue, have you seen any specific options in the boot menu (the one that shows "Run ubuntu", etc.) related to alternative graphical modes? I don't remember how it's called, but I think the boot menu has an option to let you boot in a lower resolution or in plain VGA... Also, when you say Radeon HD 5600/5700, is that one single card, or do you have two/more cards? If you have multiple cards/adapters, you might want to try to plug your monitor into another VGA/DVI plug (resp. the blue and white ports).

Comment: Your CPU looks relatively recent, and should therefore support the 64-bit OS. This means that you *can* install the 64-bit version, BUT you can also install the 32-bit version. You should be fine with the version you downloaded (looking at the filename, it seems like that's the 32-bit version).

Comment: There are 5 option, run,install,test memory,advanced option,help..
advanced option is empty;help has something, said I can press F1~Fx
I did not see very clearly...
I only have one video card, it seam to be 5650,and i use software to check the video card, it display the 5600/5700...
I will try again the help menu...

Comment: @Mr.Pixel,Help has F2~F10, but I can not find helpful message for me!~

Comment: Finally,I decide to download amd64 version, and will try again tomorrow!~

Comment: I download amd64 version and still the same problem...

Comment: I have some new information about my installing.
I download the amd64 version, use usb to install,have same problem.
And I try to use the wubi in the amd64.iso to install, choose the "safe graphic mode" and install some times and finally success;
Then, because I have two hard disk, I want to install ubuntu on one;I make the disk as a new disk driver in windows,and using wubi to install on the disk, choose "safe graphic mode";But, when stalling the screen will be black and the screen power light is dark...
I guess whether the power of my computer can not support two disk?@Mr.Pixel

Answer (score 1):

What, specifically, are the results? I usually burn the disc image to a CD and then boot from said CD, do any necessary partitioning, and then complete the installation. I've never had good luck with the USB method.

Comment: I personally never had any trouble installing from a *freshly-created* USB disk, following the instructions on the ubuntu Download page (where it lets you choose "I will be installing from a USB disk" or "I will be..."). But I'm insisting, it's better to use a freshly-created USB, and not one that has been created a month ago and on which other files have been added.

Comment: My DC driver is very old..I can not burn a CD...

Comment: @Mr.Pixel What do you mean freshly-created USB?

Comment: @Mr.Pixel I format my usb disk and use universal-usb-installer

Comment: Yes, freshly created USB means you just used universal-usb-installer. Now I just think of a little detail: while you created your USB, did you select the correct Ubuntu version in the universal-usb-installer? It's stated as "Step 1: Select a linux distribution from ...". If you downloaded the default Ubuntu 11.10 image, you *must* have selected Ubuntu 11.10 desktop.

If you're not sure, feel free to recreate your USB.

I know it may sound like a stupid suggestion, but who never made a stupid mistake? :-)

Comment: yes,I choose the correct version.